# Schrodinger's Bug: PyQt QTimer event only triggered if there was a breakpoint on startTimer()

Tags: debugging, timer, pyqt4

This is a miracle bug: the behaviour, print output, and branching of this code changes based on what breakpoints are placed, not based on the actual code.

Start with one breakpoint in `timerEvent()`.

This breakpoint in `timerEvent()` is **not** triggered.

However when I set a *second* breakpoint on `startTimer()` -- but change NOTHING else, then the breakpoint in `timerEvent()` **is** now tiggered.

```
#!/bin/python2
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QMainWindow, QApplication

class SchrodingersWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, flags=0):
        super(QMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.startTimer(0) # Try setting a breakpoint here

    def timerEvent(self, event):
        print "Something Timer Happened" # This never gets called unless the breakpoint is set on startTimer()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    SchrodingersWindow()
    app.exec_()
```

Schrodinger's bug.  Tested in pyqt w/ wing debugger

Tested with multiple versions of Wing debugger, and with two computers, and with Windows, and with Ubuntu.

To test this, you need a python debugger (I recommend Wing) python 2.7 and PyQt4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because as soon as `SchrodingersWindow()` completes, the object holding the window is deleted, because you never store a reference. If you debug within `__init__`, the object is in the process of being created and `SchrodingersWindow()` has not yet returned - the deletion hasn't yet happened. Compare with

```
win = SchrodingersWindow()
```

which executes the `timerEvent` every time.

Comment: If a breakpoint is set within `__init__`, then after it returns, the object will be kept alive. If you "continue" in the debugger, the `timerEvent` will be repeatedly called, which shows that the event loop must have started (i.e. the `app.exec_()` line has been reached). So the debugger *does* change the way the script would normally behave, because the window would normally be garbage-collected as soon as the penultimate line was executed. But there are no "bugs" or "miracles" here - it's just a side-effect of how debuggers work. (PS: I tested most of this in the Eric IDE).

Comment: I am not used to working in 'garbage collected' languages, and had no idea the debugger can affect garbage collection. Now that I know this, I would have been able to solve this! Thank you for your help, you made so much sense of this